# How to print lines extracted from a log file within a specified time range?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, grep

I'd like to fetch result, let's say from `2017-12-19 19:14` till the entire day from a log file that looks like this -

```
/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog_1.txt:2017-12-19 19:14:00.723 Info: Saving /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00001829
/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog_1.txt:2017-12-19 19:14:01.134 Info: Saved 9 MB at 22 MB/sec to /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00001829
/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog_1.txt:2017-12-19 19:14:01.376 Info: Merging 19 MB from /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/0000182a and /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00001829 to /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/0000182c, timestamp=15137318408510140
/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog_1.txt:2017-12-19 19:14:02.585 Info: Merged 18 MB in 1 sec at 15 MB/sec to /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/0000182c
/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog_1.txt:2017-12-19 19:14:05.200 Info: Deleted 15 MB at 337 MB/sec /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/0000182a
/var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog_1.txt:2017-12-19 19:14:05.202 Info: Deleted 9 MB at 4274 MB/sec /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/Meters/00001829
```

I am new to Unix and familiar with grep command. I tried the below command

```
date="2017-12-19 [19-23]:[14-59]"
echo "$date"
grep "$date" $root_path_values
```

but it throws invalid range end error. Any solution ? The date is going to be coming from a variable so it will be unpredictable. Therefore, don't make a command just keeping the example in mind. $root_path_values is a sequence of error files like errorLog.txt, errorLog_1.txt, errorLog_2.txt and so on.

Comment: see https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions regarding `[]`.. they won't do what you think they should...

Comment: see https://www.regular-expressions.info/numericranges.html for how to construct numeric ranges

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to fetch result, let's say from `2017-12-19 19:14` till the entire day … The date is going to be coming from a variable …

This is not a job for regular expressions. Since the timestamp has a sensible form, we can simply compare it as a whole, e. g.:

```
start='2017-12-19 19:14'
end='2017-12-20'
awk -vstart="$start" -vend=$end 'start <= $0 && $0 < end' ErrorLog_1.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

`egrep '2017-12-19 (19|2[0-3])\:(1[4-9]|[2-5][0-9])\:*\.*' path/to/your/file` Try this regexp.

In the case if you need pattern in variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
date="2017-12-19 (19|2[0-3])\:(1[4-9]|[2-5][0-9])\:*\.*"
egrep ${date} path/to/your/file
```

Comment: can you explain this regex in detail?

Comment: @rishabhv66 first part: `(19|2[0-3])` finding correct hour substring, means `(19 or (20 or 21 or 22 or 23))`, second part between two `\:` is `(1[4-9]|[2-5][0-9])` its finding minutes like: ((14 or 15 or 16 or 17 or 18 or 19) or (<many numbers from 20 to 59))`. The last `*\.*`, here first `*` means 'any string in seconds place', `\.` just a point, last `*` means 'any string in milliseconds'. For clearly understanding of the first part: `2[0-9]` means "string with two chars, where first char is 2, the second char anything between 0 and 9".

Comment: So the full regex could be read as: "(19 or "two-chars-long string where first char is '2' and the second anything between 0 and 3"):("two-chars-long string where first char is '1' and the second anything between 4 and 9" or "two-chars-long string where first chat is anything between 2 and 5; the second char anything is between 0 and 9"):"doesn't matter what kind of string"."doesn't matter what kind of sting"

Comment: actually the date will come from a variable so it is not always going to be 9:14...It will be unpredictable

Comment: @rishabhv66 no problem, put pattern inside of the variable. Edited my solution.

Comment: No no...I'm saying dates are unpredictable..If for instance date recieved is 2017-12-19 19:14 then next time I might receive 2017-11-18 08:04

Comment: mm, in this case you can just edit date variable. If you needs dynamic generated `$date`, let me know how you should find time interval?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161724/discussion-between-rishabhv66-and-viktor-khilin).